# libc++_shared.so is missing

Tags: c++, android-ndk, sdl, llvm-clang

My .apk successfully loads on to my android device which is a Huawei Y6. I am using clang as my compiler and I am compiling from the command line. However when I launch it I get an SDL Error that reads

```
SDL Error

An error occurred while trying to start the application. Please try again and 
or reinstall.

Error:
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.tutorial.game-2/base.apk"], nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,/system/lib]]] couldn't find "libc++_shared.so"
```

I'm not sure why this is, since when I run my ndk-build I get these messages:

```
[armeabi] Install       : libc++_shared.so => libs/armeabi/libc++_shared.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install   : libc++_shared.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so
[x86] Install           : libc++_shared.so => libs/x86/libc++_shared.so
```

Here is my Application.mk

```
APP_STL := c++_shared

#LIBCXX_FORCE_REBUILD := true

APP_OPTIM := release

APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti

APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions

APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86

APP_MODULES := main

# Min SDK level
APP_PLATFORM=android-18

NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
```

And here is my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := main

SDL_PATH := ../SDL2

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions -std=c++14 -DGLEW_NO_GLU -D_ANDROID_ -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
# -Wall

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(SDL_PATH)/include \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(SDL_PATH)/include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../SDL2_image \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../common/include

# Add your application source files here...
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SDL_PATH)/src/main/android/SDL_android_main.c \
    Source.cpp

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := SDL2 SDL2_mixer SDL2_image
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := freetype2-static

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv3 -llog -lz    

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I'm unclear what is meant by libc++_shared.so can't be found. Could someone please explain what I should be doing here?

Comment: export  the file  libc++_shared.so to the path of your compiler PathClassLoader, if it still complains or its already on the path, think of probably upgrading to a newer version of libc++

Comment: and check if its also in the path of your native Library Directories, if not add it

Comment: Hi, this is probably a really ameteur question, but could you explain how I do this.

Comment: first you check the path your compiler uses, try doing it this way and see: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/libs/armeabi:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: But if your compiler has custom settings and it doesnt work then try finding the path your compiler looks for its shared object files, its pretty easy, once you find that path and it contains a list of .so files, try copying the path of the libc++_shared.so file to that path

Comment: let me know how it goes/

Comment: try this as well copy "libs/armeabi/libc++_shared.so" file to  "/vendor/lib" and "/system/lib" directories